# Thread safe circular buffer?

Tags: java, thread-safety

I got 2 threads, one inserts data and second thread retrieves data.
I got very strange results.

Is it thread safe?

if not, how to fix it?

this is my circular buffer:

```
private int mBufferSize;
    private int startPointer = 0;
    private int endPointer = 0;
    private int bufferSize = 0;
    private String[] buffer;

    public BBuffer(int size) {
        mBufferSize = size;
        startPointer = 0;
        endPointer = 0;
        bufferSize = 0;
        buffer = new String[mBufferSize];
    }


    public String[] getData() {
        String data = null;

        if (!isEmpty()) {
            bufferSize--;
            startPointer = (startPointer + 1) % mBufferSize;
            data = (String) buffer[startPointer];


        } else {

            System.err.println("!");
            return null;
        }

        return data.split(",");
    }

    public  void addData(String data) {
        if (!isFull()) {
            bufferSize++;
            endPointer = (endPointer + 1) % mBufferSize;
            buffer[endPointer] = data;
            System.out.println("->"+data);
        } else {
            System.out.println("full");
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return bufferSize == 0;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return bufferSize == mBufferSize;
    }

}
```

Comment: is this a homework? if so, can you please tag it with 'homework'?

Comment: I suspect that addData and getData should be synchronized.  If one thread calls add while another is in the middle of get, or vica versa, say, in the middle of the hairy math with the div operator, bad things could happen.

Answer (score 3):

Not thread safe at all.

You just have to add the `synchronized` keyword to the declaration of your 4 methods.  You are lucky that such a simple solution works for your class because it is not always the case.

One potentially tricky issue is the `String[]` returned by `getData`.  You make a new array at each invocation, so you don't have any problems, but it would have been complicated to synchronize if it had returned some reference to an inner array.

Comment: Can you please explain a little bit more why synchronized keywords is enough in this case? thanks

Comment: Each method leaves the object in a consistent state.  A counter-example would be a class with methods `setFirstName` and `setLastName`; even if both methods are synchronized, you would have some time periods where the object is an inconsistent state with a first name that doesn't correspond to the last name.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not thread safe. 
If `getData()` and `addData()` are called from 2 different threads then you are 100% sure you will run into trouble mainly because `bufferSize` will be accessed by both threads; the one calling `getData()` and the other calling `addData()`.
To fix this, you should first acquire a lock before modifying the `bufferSize` member variable.
[This](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/memory.doc.html) should help you get started with threads and locks and how to protect shared resources.

Answer (score 0):

For this you use a semaphore since you are using a basic array. Arraylists can be used as a threadsafe method of doing it. But with your implementation you want to create a semaphore then in each method that uses the buffer call semaphore.aquire() and when you are done call semaphore.release()